# If else loops to satisfy multiple conditions

Tags: java, loops

How to return 2 types if the numbers fulfil more than 2 conditions?

The output I got so far is:
Enter three integers: 8 8 8
<8, 8, 8> is an Isosceles triangle

```
private Types getTypes ()
{
    int a = getA();
    int b = getB();
    int c = getC();

    if ((a+b) > c || (a+c) > b || (b+c) > a )
    {
        if (a==b || a==c || b==c)
        {
            return Types.Isosceles;
        }
        if (a == b && b == c && c==a)
        {
            return Types.Equilateral;
        }

        else
        {
            return Types.Scalene;
        }
    }
    else
        return Types.NoShape;
}
```

Ideal output would be
     Enter three intergers: 8 8 8
     <8, 8, 8> is an equilateral triangle
     <8, 8, 8> is an isosceles triangle
     <8, 8, 8> is a triangle

Comment: and do you have a question?

Comment: `==` is transitive, so if have `a == b && b == c` then have also `a==c`

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

You could instead return a `Set<Types>` because a set can hold multiple items. At the start of your method, create a set to add all the types to. Then, you can add to it in the rest of the method.

```
private Set<Types> getTypes() {
    Set<Types> set = EnumSet.noneOf(Types.class);
    int a = getA();
    int b = getB();
    int c = getC();

    if ((a+b) > c || (a+c) > b || (b+c) > a) {
        if (a==b || a==c || b==c) {
            set.add(Types.Isosceles);
        }
        if (a == b && b == c && c==a) {
            set.add(Types.Equilateral);
        } else {
            set.add(Types.Scalene);
        }
    }
    if (set.isEmpty()) {
        set.add(Types.NoShape);
    }
    return set;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Assuming `Types` is an `enum`, you could even use an `EnumSet` instead of a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to return two separate variable in Java.

The simplest way to solve this would be do declare an Array and return the two variables that you need to return within the Array. E.g.

```
Types[] ret = new Types[2];
ret[0] = Types.equilateral;
ret[1] = Types.isosceles;
return ret;
```

This will return the two values equilateral and isosceles within the Array. That should be proper syntax for a Types array.

Comment: An array might not be the best solution as it only has a fixed size and could have empty/null values. A `Collection` like a `Set` or `List` might work better

Comment: If you need to have an undefined number of variables use an arraylist. An array takes up the least memory, and collections can slow down runtime due to extra memory allocation.

Comment: A set works just as well? A set is an unordered list which does not have duplicate values. Since they need to return multiple enums, a set would be fine for this because
A) they are not going to have duplicate enums in the set
B) ordering is unnecessary in this situation so a list is not needed

Comment: Just because an array may take up the least amount of memory doesn't mean it is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a StringBuilder to store results separated by a delimiter of your choice and then split the resultant string to get you multiple results.

```
private static String getTypes ()
    {
        int a = getA();
        int b = getB();
        int c = getC();

        Types  [] answer = new Types[4];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");


        if ((a+b) > c || (a+c) > b || (b+c) > a )
        {
            if ((a==b || a==c || b==c))
            {
                sb.append(Types.Isosceles)
                sb.append(DELIMITER); // DELIMITER is a character of you choice... 

            }
            if (a == b && b == c && c==a)
            {
                sb.append(Types.Equilateral);
                sb.append(DELIMITER);
            } else {
                sb.append(Types.Scalene);
                sb.append(DELIMITER);
            }
        }
        else{
            sb.append(Types.NoShape);
            sb.append(DELIMITER);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: How would this help them? They want to use the Type(s) returned from the method to display more info, not have a string representing the types

Comment: This method precisely returns a delimiter separated String where in each String corresponds to an object of type `Type`. They can always get a Type object using this string.

Comment: I feel this would be more counterintuitive than useful

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility instead of a collection of some kind is you can make a simple object such as

```
class ShapeInfo {
    private final boolean isosceles;
    private final boolean equilateral;
    private final boolean scalene;
    public ShapeInfo(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a + b > c || a + c > b || b + c > a) {
            equilateral = a == b && a == c && b == c;
            isosceles = a == b || a == c || b == c;
            scalene = !equilateral && !isosceles;
        } else {
            equilateral = false;
            isosceles = false;
            scalene = false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        // TODO your print method here using the private instance variables
    }
    // add getters if you need them

}
```

This way the constructor takes care of the object's properties and the code is easily portable (self contained here).

```
ShapeInfo shapeInfo = new ShapeInfo(8, 8, 8);
System.out.println(shapeInfo);
```